# Matter.js How to keep adding Bodies to the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d, matter.js

```
var ball = Bodies.circle(400, 20, 23, {
    density: 0.0005,
    frictionAir: 0.06,
    restitution: 0.3,       
    friction: 0.01,
    render: {
        sprite: {
            texture: 'face2.png',
        }
    }
});

$('.add').on('click', function() {
    World.add(engine.world, ball);
})
```

This is working for me, it adds one Circle. But when I click again nothing happens.

Im guessing im not creating a new object.

My goal is to be able to press the button ( .add ) and for every time i press it, it adds a new circle to the World.

Comment: @Grimbode, that worked! Why did you remove you're answer?

Comment: It was more of a guess to be honest. I'll put it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that "ball" is an instance created from Bodies. You should make an instance for every ball you want to add to the world.

```
var ball = function () {

    return Bodies.circle(400, 20, 23, {
        density: 0.0005,
        frictionAir: 0.06,
        restitution: 0.3,
        friction: 0.01,
        render: {
            sprite: {
                texture: 'face2.png',
            }
        }
    });
}

$('.add').on('click', function () {
    World.add(engine.world, ball());
})
```